# sharing a java object between two HttpRequests

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 submit buttons on my web UI.

When first submit button is pressed, control goes to a servlet, back-end operations happen and a EmployeeInfo class (setter-getter class) gets some of its fields(member variables) set.

The control goes back to UI and I press second submit button.

Now in the same servlet, can I get that same object of EmployeeInfo with its fields having the same values? Other than using session object.

Comment: Can you not store the object into session and reuse it?

Comment: so what kind of answer you expect here? 'Yes or No' answer?

Comment: Yes. Through the magic of an `HTTPSession`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to store it in session object.In that case , you must remove it from session once it's use is completed.If you dont want to use session, then set hidden fields in UI corresponding to fields in your object.Then while second submit, get these values back into your object by reading request parameters.

Comment: You cant get object from request.You have to set each field in your object to a hidden field and while second submit, you will get all these fields as string from request object.Using these values, you have to construct a new object.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a ***stateless protocol***, so any information you need to share on the server side has to be *persisted* in some form.

One option is to store it in [Session](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
```

This is how you lookup a session related to a request.

Use the getter/setter pair for getting and setting the properties you wish to persist

[`HttpSession#setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
session.setAttribute("name",value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and probably the most correct) way would be to keep it in the session until it's fully constructed.

You could store it in the database too, but then it would require that the object doesn't need to be fully constructed before saving. But I could imagine there are some edge cases where this would be a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Store object to [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) after first request

```
EmployeeInfo info = ..
// ...
request.getSession().setAttribute("EMPLOYEE_INFO", info); // store object to http session
```

get object from `HttpSession` at second request

```
EmployeeInfo info = (EmployeeInfo)request.getSession().getAttribute("EMPLOYEE_INFO");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for your situation: Either have a *stateful server* or a *stateless server (REST)*:

**Stateful server**

If you are fine with having client state on the server, you should use a `HttpSession` to store the intermediate results (see other answers for details). Please note that you might get into troubles if a user duplicates his browser tab because both tabs then will share the same session on the server.

But as you wrote you don't want to use a session object, consider this:

**Stateless Server (REST)**

If you want to avoid holding state on the server, simply do it on the client and transfer all requried state to the server on every request.

This approach is also called *REST* (Representational State Transfer). There is a Java standard for that: [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services).

But you are not forced to use that API. If you've got a HTML client, you could simply store all data in hidden fields so it will be transferred to the server on submit. Therefore you need some server side scripting (e.h. JSP) to generate the hidden fields into the second HTML form.